# unable to find closest label text in JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to access label text which is nearby checkbox. I am using Visual Studio and C#.

HTML PAGE

```
<td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CHKBranches_0" type="checkbox" 
name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CHKBranches$0">
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CHKBranches_0">Kolkatta (EJAA)</label></td>
```

jquery script for access text

```
var strBr = "";             
$("input[id*='CHKBranches']").each(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {                   
     // Note : successfully check checkbox but unable to find closest label text                          
        strBr += $(this).closest('label').text() +",";
    }
});
```

Comment: use `.next()` since it is next to checkbox

Comment: Thanks man ... its working now

Comment: glad it works now mate

Comment: but there is another problem of value,  getting from .next is Kolkatta (EJAA)  and i want only EJAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just move up to the parent and then find the label?

jQuery

```
var strBr = ""; 
  $("input[id*='CHKBranches']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {                   
      var $parent = $(this).parent();               
      strBr += $parent.closest('label').text() +",";
    }
  });
```

Comment: @AjayK If this is the correct answer please tick it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to find a label because of the way how `.closest()` works. It looks at parent nodes. You should replace `.closest()` with `.siblings()` in order to search nodes which are at the same level in the DOM tree.

https://jsfiddle.net/oogjs0r5/